# how to change cardbackground dynamicaly taking image from array, and how to repeate these image array?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview, cardview

here is my view binder code -

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardContentHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem item = listdata.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.subtitle.setText(item.getSubtitle());
    holder.datetime.setText(item.getTimestamp());
   holder.datetimeii.setText(item.getTimestampii());
    String outImage=item.getImage();
    String outImageii=item.getImageii();


    final int THUMBSIZE = 64;


    if(!outImage.isEmpty()) {
        holder.secondaryicon.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outImage),
                THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
        holder.secondaryicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.secondaryicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(!outImageii.isEmpty()) {
        holder.secondaryiconii.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outImageii),
                THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
        holder.secondaryiconii.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.secondaryiconii.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (Pref.getmInstance(context).getTheme() == 4) {
        holder.title.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        holder.subtitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textGreyHeader));
        holder.datetime.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textGreyHeader));
        //holder.datetime.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
    if (Pref.getmInstance(context).getTheme() == 2) {
    if(position==0){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textGreyHeader));

    }
    }
    // no-op
}
```

in theme 2 i want [cardview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAH1a.png) like this image.

which while scrolling background cardview image should be continuous loading.
in 6 image group repeating pattern.

thanks.

Comment: get item position and modulo operation. if remainder is 0 set one color as card backgroundcolor,1 another and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper method to loop over your resources

```
@DrawableRes
private int getBackgroundImageResource(int position,  int[] imageResources) {
    return imageResources[position % imageResources.length];
}
```

Declare an int drawable array globally

```
int[] imageResources = new int[]{
                R.drawable.ic_account_box_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp
                // Feel free to add more resources
        };
```

and call the method in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
int backgroundImage = getBackgroundImageResource(position, imageResources);
```

Comment: ok, thanks, i did what you said. but, how do i set to cardview                        back ground,              holder.itemView.setBackground(context,backgroundImage);  sorry for that, i am new to android.

Comment: Try this?
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardBackgroundColor(int)